# How to redirect output while using a here document

Tags: shell, io-redirection, here-document

How to redirect the output of below command in shell into logfile.

```
sqlplus -s "/nolog" <<EOF
conn / as sysdba
@?/sqlpatch/19282021/postinstall.sql
exit;
EOF
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use redirection operator `>` at the first line:

```
sqlplus -s "/nolog" <<EOF >logfile
conn / as sysdba
@?/sqlpatch/19282021/postinstall.sql
exit;
EOF
```

You can also write `>logfile` at the beginning of the line, what is equally legal syntax in most shells, but less commonly practiced.

```
>logfile sqlplus -s "/nolog" <<EOF
conn / as sysdba
@?/sqlpatch/19282021/postinstall.sql
exit;
EOF
```

Comment: And you can (probably) put redirection immediately after the command word: `sqlplus >logfile -s` etc.

Comment: @PM2Ring that is true, although splitting the command and its options with redirections is extremely confusing. The reason it works is that shell first assigns all redirections and only then actually starts the commands. That is also the reason why `cat file >file` doesn't work as expected - shell first redirect the output to `file` (and in the process truncate the file) and only then goes back to `cat`, but at this point `cat` reads only empty file.

Comment: Ah, good point. I don't find it confusing because I got used to putting redirections immediately after the command word many years ago in good old AmigaDOS, so it looks quite normal to me. :)