# Piping the results from an SSH command to be saved locally

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, output

I've the following command in a script that I want to run that will happily output the result of all the remote commands to STDOUT on the console.

```bsh
ssh -t my-server1.my-domain.net  << EOF
    ./bin/myApp
    echo "Hello World"
    ls ~/
EOF
```

How would I go about saving the results of this output to my local machine. I've tried both using normal piping tee or redirecting the stream to a file using `>` eg.

```bsh
ssh -t my-server1.my-domain.net  << EOF
    ./bin/myApp
    echo "Hello World"
    ls ~/
EOF 2&>1 test.txt
```

or

```bsh
ssh -t my-server1.my-domain.net  << EOF
    ./bin/myApp
    echo "Hello World"
    ls ~/
EOF 2&>1 | tee test.txt
```

I'd like to see the commands run on the remote machine, output to the console, and write to a file on the local machine.

Comment: Are you looking for something like https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/173931/315749 ?

Comment: Actually, that answer is exactly what I'm looking for. ( I didn't even think to include the piping at the initial EOF line )

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by piping on the same line as the `ssh` command and not after the ssh command.

To pipe to both `STDOUT` and `test.txt`, you can use:

```bsh
ssh -t my-server1.my-domain.net  << EOF | tee test.txt
    ./bin/myApp
    echo "Hello World"
    ls ~/
EOF
```

To just output to `test.txt` (not `STDOUT`) you can use:

```bsh
ssh -t my-server1.my-domain.net  << EOF > test.txt
    ./bin/myApp
    echo "Hello World"
    ls ~/
EOF
```