# Pipe or Redirect output: Linux (Remote) to Win (Local)

Tags: ssh, io-redirection

the following answer the question, but they're either using the HEREDOC syntax, as part of the SSH command itself, or a combination of both.

@[askubuntu - output-from-remote-machine-to-local-file-via-ssh](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917200/how-to-redirect-command-output-from-remote-machine-to-local-file-via-ssh)

@[Unix & Linux - piping-the-results](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/693727/piping-the-results-from-an-ssh-command-to-be-saved-locally)

@[Unix & Linux - how-to-redirect-output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/173931/how-to-redirect-output-while-using-a-here-document)

[1] Can the same thing be achieved while connected to the remote machine? e.g. i've executed the SSH command hours ago and executed several different operations on the remote machine. Now, I'd like to execute another while only that stdout is piped / redirected to the local machine.

[2] What is the specification for the resulting file? e.g. `SSH ... >logfile`

That is "where do i find it on the local box?"

Comment: If the local environment is Windows and the local SSH client is Windows, then you're asking how to do output redirection in Windows programs instead of Linux ones.  After all, on the remote Linux server, the output from commands/scripts is already being delivered back to the local Windows computer, else the output wouldn't display on your screen.  Linux is already doing what you need, it's the Windows programs you're asking to change function.  This might not be the right forum.

Comment: Not sure actually, that's been so long ago. Probably was using the Windows Subsystem for Linux when the question was asked. 

Are you advising that if i'm performing the operation from a linux box, the >logfile is placed into the current working directory?